# marked region does not highlight in emacs after changing the buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm creating a custom .emacs file (using GNU Emacs 24.3.1) and in it I have a custom function, bound to a custom shortcut, that copies the selected region "(kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))" then pastes it in a different location.  Then I try to select a new region. But when I do, the region is no longer highlighted.  The mark IS set, because I can copy/paste.

If I skip the paste step in my function, the new region is highlighted.  It's just that editing the buffer in any way causes region highlighting to stop working.

From https://www.fnal.gov/docs/products/emacs/emacs/emacs_12.html :
"Any change to the buffer, such as inserting or deleting a character, deactivates the mark. This means any subsequent command that operates on a region will get an error and refuse to operate. You can make the region active again by typing C-x C-x. "

C-x C-x simply calls (exchange-point-and-mark), but if I call (exchange-point-and-mark) in my function, highlighting still does not turn on again.  Why not?

Disclaimer: I am not that familiar with emacs, I'm just trial and erroring to some working code, but I just can't find a way to highlight the selected region after I edit the buffer.  My workaround is to call a different function in my .emacs, bound to a different shortcut, that simply calls (exchange-point-and-mark) and the previously selected region is highlighted.

EDIT: adding representative code

```
(defun func1 ()
  (interactive)
  (set-mark (point))
  (forward-char)
  (forward-char) ; at this point two characters are highlighted
  (set-mark (point))
  (forward-char)
  (forward-char) ; at this point two different characters are highlighted
)

(defun func2 ()
  (interactive)
  (set-mark (point))
  (forward-char)
  (forward-char) ; at this point two characters are highlighted
  (insert "a")
  (set-mark (point))
  (forward-char)
  (forward-char) ; at this point nothing is highlighted because of the insert, but the mark IS set
)

(defun func3 ()
  ; if I call this right after calling func2 the region is highlighted
  (interactive)
  (exchange-point-and-mark)
)

(global-set-key (kbd "<f5> x") 'func1)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5> c") 'func2)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5> v") 'func3)
```

Comment: Show your code. We cannot guess what you are doing.

Comment: added. had to clean it up

Answer (score 1):

[this is a re-edit after the discussion in the comments]

After making sure `transient-mark-mode` is enabled (it is what does the hilighting) there may not be much else that can be done to make this work.

My speculation is that `transient-mark-mode` works during the idle time between key inputs and it is perhaps simply testing whether the buffer was modified since the last time it ran or not, in which case any function which both attempts to set and activate the mark such that some hilighting is displayed, while at the same time modifying the buffer, will never succeed in triggering `transient-mark-mode` to hilight anything.

Comment: (transient-mark-mode 1) has no effect (I tried various combinations)

Comment: Did you check the active modes for the buffer before (and after) trying your tests?  (i.e. call `describe-mode`)

Comment: fundamental mode the whole time with:
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Delete-Selection File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Font-Lock Gpm-Mouse
Line-Number Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark
Xterm-Mouse

The minor modes did not change

Comment: Hmmm.... OK, so `transient-mark-mode` does indeed appear to be enabled, and to stay enabled.  The affect you see is possibly a bug, though it may also have to do with how and when `transient-mark-mode` (which is implemented in C, not elisp) detects if there was a modification to the buffer, i.e. whether it should do anything.  My guess is it only tries between top-level interactively called functions, and since in your `func2 the buffer is modified within that top-level function, it doesn't think it should do any hilighting once that function returns.

Comment: is it possible to somehow trigger two top-level functions to run interactively with one hot key?

Comment: I tried using `call-interactively` to call your test function, but that didn't seem to make any difference.  I'm speculating quite a bit and not 100% sure but I think the hilighting is done in the idle time between key (and other) inputs (I have not looked at the C code), so calling a function which modifies a buffer, even if doing so "interactively" will still make it appear to the hilighting engine that the buffer was modified during the execution of the last interactively called function, so perhaps there is literally no way to do what you're asking.

Comment: "there is literally no way to do what you're asking" - put that as an answer :)